# python - combining argsort with masking to get nearest values in moving window

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, large-data

I have some code for calculating missing values in an image, based on neighbouring values in a 2D circular window. It also uses the values from one or more temporally-adjacent images at the same locations (i.e. the same 2D window shifted in the 3rd dimension).

For each position that is missing, I need to calculate the value based not necessarily on all the values available in the whole window, but only on the spatially-nearest n cells that do have values (in both images / Z-axis positions), where n is some value less than the total number of cells in the 2D window.

At the minute, it's much quicker to calculate for everything in the window, because my means  of sorting to get the nearest n cells with data is the slowest part of the function as it has to be repeated each time even though the distances in terms of window coordinates do not change. I'm not sure this is necessary and feel I must be able to get the sorted distances once, and then mask those in the process of only selecting available cells.

Here's my code for selecting the data to use within a window of the gap cell location:

```
# radius will in reality be ~100
radius = 2
y,x = np.ogrid[-radius:radius+1, -radius:radius+1]
dist = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
circle_template = dist > radius

# this will in reality be a very large 3 dimensional array
# representing daily images with some gaps, indicated by 0s
dataStack = np.zeros((2,5,5))
dataStack[1] = (np.random.random(25) * 100).reshape(dist.shape)
dataStack[0] = (np.random.random(25) * 100).reshape(dist.shape)

testdata = dataStack[1]
alternatedata = dataStack[0]
random_gap_locations = (np.random.random(25) * 30).reshape(dist.shape) > testdata
testdata[random_gap_locations] = 0
testdata[radius, radius] = 0

# in reality we will go through every gap (zero) location in the data 
# for each image and for each gap use slicing to get a window of 
# size (radius*2+1, radius*2+1) around it from each image, with the 
# gap being at the centre i.e. 
# testgaplocation = [radius, radius]
# and the variables testdata, alternatedata below will refer to these 
# slices

locations_to_exclude = np.logical_or(circle_template, np.logical_or
                                     (testdata==0, alternatedata==0))
# the places that are inside the circular mask and where both images 
# have data 
locations_to_include = ~locations_to_exclude
number_available = np.count_nonzero(locations_to_include)

# we only want to do the interpolation calculations from the nearest n 
# locations that have data available, n will be ~100 in reality
number_required = 3

available_distances = dist[locations_to_include]
available_data = testdata[locations_to_include]
available_alternates = alternatedata[locations_to_include]

if number_available > number_required:
    # In this case we need to find the closest number_required of elements, based
    # on distances recorded in dist, from available_data and available_alternates
    # Having to repeat this argsort for each gap cell calculation is slow and feels 
    # like it should be avoidable
    sortedDistanceIndices = available_distances.argsort(kind = 'mergesort',axis=None)
    requiredIndices = sortedDistanceIndices[0:number_required]
    selected_data = np.take(available_data, requiredIndices)
    selected_alternates = np.take(available_alternates , requiredIndices)
else:
    # we just use available_data and available_alternates as they are...

# now do stuff with the selected data to calculate a value for the gap cell
```

This works, but over half of the total time of the function is taken in the argsort of the masked spatial distance data. (~900uS of a total 1.4mS - and this function will be running tens of billions of times, so this is an important difference!)

I am sure that I must be able to just do this argsort once outside of the function, when the spatial distance window is originally set up, and then include those sort indices in the masking, to get the first howManyToCalculate indices without having to re-do the sort. The answer might involve putting the various bits that we are extracting from, into a record array - but I can't figure out how, if so. Can anyone see how I can make this part of the process more efficient?

Comment: Your code is really hard to read... You may want to read [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and follow it: it facilitates sharing code with other Python programmers.

Comment: I agree with Jaime that this is rather difficult to read, especially the code, but the description leaves some room for interpretation, too. So I will not venture to provide an answer, but here are some tools I would check out if I were to (if I at least vaguely understand your problem correctly). [sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/image.py#L238) gives you a view on your patches, which you can mask. It will create a copy, so beware of memory issues.

Comment: You may also be interested in a seemingly completely unrelated function, which imputes missing values using dilations. It won't give you your exact result, but may be a good proxy: [nilearn.masking._extrapolate_out_img](https://github.com/nilearn/nilearn/blob/fd7e7a7186dca43d0ef5ebd19990b0751d476bda/nilearn/masking.py#L65)

Comment: Fair comment, I've clarified the questions and replaced the code sample with a simpler bit that doesn't show the setting up of the moving window / handling of the boundaries

Comment: Record arrays, or structured arrays for that matter, could be convenient to do (boolean) indexing operations on multiple data sets in a single operation. For large indexing operations it may also be faster that way.

Comment: @moarningsun - yes, boolean indexing on a single structured array appears to be the most efficient way of doing this. Interestingly np.compress seems to be slow on structured arrays compared to boolean indexing, whereas np.take is much faster than fancy indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to do the sorting outside of the loop:

```
sorted_dist_idcs = dist.argsort(kind='mergesort', axis=None)
```

Then using some variables from the original code, this is what I could come up with, though it still feels like a major round-trip..

```
loc_to_incl_sorted = locations_to_include.take(sorted_dist_idcs)
sorted_dist_idcs_to_incl = sorted_dist_idcs[loc_to_incl_sorted]

required_idcs = sorted_dist_idcs_to_incl[:number_required]
selected_data = testdata.take(required_idcs)
selected_alternates = alternatedata.take(required_idcs)
```

Note the `required_idcs` refer to locations in the `testdata` and not `available_data` as in the original code. And this snippet I used `take` for the purpose of conveniently indexing the flattened array.

Comment: Thanks! This answers the question as I phrased it in my edited version so I've accepted the answer. However it doesn't quite work with the "real" data, when the gap is < radius from the edge of the data. In these cases testdata and alternatedata are taken as a slice that is the original (diam*diam) size, but trimmed to ensure it doesn't overlap the edge of the data.  Then the numbers in sorted_dist_idcs_to_incl don't correspond any more with the indices of the trimmed array slices. However I have figured out a solution based on your input which I'll post shortly.

Answer (score 0):

@moarningsun - thanks for the comment and answer.  These got me on the right track, but don't quite work for me when the gap is < radius from the edge of the data: in this case I use a window around the gap cell which is "trimmed" to the data bounds. In this situation the indices reflect the "full" window and thus can't be used to select cells from the bounded window.

Unfortunately I edited that part of my code out when I clarified the original question but it's turned out to be relevant.

I've realised now that if you use `argsort` again on the output of `argsort` then you get ranks; i.e. the position that each item would have when the overall array was sorted. We can safely mask these and then take the smallest `number_required` of them (and do this on a structured array to get the corresponding data at the same time).

This implies another sort within the loop, but in fact we can use partitioning rather than a full sort, because all we need is the smallest `num_required` items. If `num_required` is substantially less than the number of data items then this is much faster than doing the `argsort`.

For example with `num_required` = 80 and `num_available` = 15000 the full `argsort` takes ~900µs whereas `argpartition` followed by index and slice to get the first 80 takes ~110µs. We still need to do the `argsort` to get the ranks at the outset (rather than just partitioning based on distance) in order to get the stability of the mergesort, and thus get the "right one" when distance is not unique.

My code as shown below now runs in ~610uS on real data, including the actual calculations that aren't shown here. I'm happy with that now, but there seem to be several other apparently minor factors that can have an influence on the runtime that's hard to understand.

For example putting the `circle_template` in the structured array along with `dist`, `ranks`, and another field not shown here, doubles the runtime of the overall function (even if we don't access `circle_template` in the loop!). Even worse, using `np.partition` on the structured array with `order=['ranks']` increases the overall function runtime by almost **two orders of magnitude** vs using `np.argpartition` as shown below!

```
# radius will in reality be ~100
radius = 2
y,x = np.ogrid[-radius:radius+1, -radius:radius+1]
dist = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
circle_template = dist > radius
ranks = dist.argsort(axis=None,kind='mergesort').argsort().reshape(dist.shape)
diam = radius * 2 + 1

# putting circle_template in this array too doubles overall function runtime! 
fullWindowArray = np.zeros((diam,diam),dtype=[('ranks',ranks.dtype.str),
                                       ('thisdata',dayDataStack.dtype.str),
                                       ('alternatedata',dayDataStack.dtype.str),
                                       ('dist',spatialDist.dtype.str)])
fullWindowArray['ranks'] = ranks
fullWindowArray['dist'] = dist

# this will in reality be a very large 3 dimensional array
# representing daily images with some gaps, indicated by 0s
dataStack = np.zeros((2,5,5))
dataStack[1] = (np.random.random(25) * 100).reshape(dist.shape)
dataStack[0] = (np.random.random(25) * 100).reshape(dist.shape)

testdata = dataStack[1]
alternatedata = dataStack[0]
random_gap_locations = (np.random.random(25) * 30).reshape(dist.shape) > testdata
testdata[random_gap_locations] = 0
testdata[radius, radius] = 0

# in reality we will loop here to go through every gap (zero) location in the data 
# for each image 
gapz, gapy, gapx = 1, radius, radius
desLeft, desRight = gapx - radius, gapx + radius+1
desTop, desBottom = gapy - radius, gapy + radius+1
extentB, extentR = dataStack.shape[1:]

# handle the case where the gap is < search radius from the edge of 
# the data. If this is the case, we can't use the full
# diam * diam window
dataL = max(0, desLeft)
maskL = 0 if desLeft >= 0 else abs(dataL - desLeft)
dataT = max(0, desTop)
maskT = 0 if desTop >= 0 else abs(dataT - desTop)
dataR = min(desRight, extentR)
maskR = diam if desRight <= extentR else diam - (desRight - extentR)
dataB = min(desBottom,extentB)
maskB = diam if desBottom <= extentB else diam - (desBottom - extentB)

# get the slice that we will be working within
# ranks, dist and circle are already populated
boundedWindowArray = fullWindowArray[maskT:maskB,maskL:maskR]
boundedWindowArray['alternatedata'] = alternatedata[dataT:dataB, dataL:dataR]
boundedWindowArray['thisdata'] = testdata[dataT:dataB, dataL:dataR]

locations_to_exclude = np.logical_or(boundedWindowArray['circle_template'], 
                                     np.logical_or 
                                     (boundedWindowArray['thisdata']==0, 
                                      boundedWindowArray['alternatedata']==0))
# the places that are inside the circular mask and where both images 
# have data 
locations_to_include = ~locations_to_exclude
number_available = np.count_nonzero(locations_to_include)

# we only want to do the interpolation calculations from the nearest n 
# locations that have data available, n will be ~100 in reality
number_required = 3

data_to_use = boundedWindowArray[locations_to_include]

if number_available > number_required:
    # argpartition seems to be v fast when number_required is 
    # substantially < data_to_use.size
    # But partition on the structured array itself with order=['ranks'] 
    # is almost 2 orders of magnitude slower!

    reqIndices = np.argpartition(data_to_use['ranks'],number_required)[:number_required]
    data_to_use = np.take(data_to_use,reqIndices)
else:
    # we just use available_data and available_alternates as they are...
    pass
# now do stuff with the selected data to calculate a value for the gap cell
```